# For Those who deny the deity of Jesus Christ why does He at Revelation 1:8 identify Himself as the Lord God Almighty?

Tags: nature-of-god, names-of-god

Revelation 1:8, "I am the Alpha and the Omega, says the Lord God, who is and who was and who is to come, the Almighty."

Revelation 1:11, "saying, "Write in a book what you see, and send it to the seven churches; to Ephesus and to Smyrna, and to Pergamum and to Thyatira and to Sardis and to Philadelphia and to Laodicea.'

Revelation 1:17, "And when I say Him, I fell at His feet as a dead man. And He laid His right hand upon me, saying, "Do not be afraid, I am the first and the last, Verse 18, "and the living One, and I was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore, and I have the keys of death and Hades."

Also at Revelation 22:12-13, "Behold, I am coming quickly and My reward is with Me, to render to every man according to what he has done. Vs13, "I am the Alpha and the Omega, the first and the last, the beginning and the end."

Comment: @Kris I read your source and it rightly says that both "expressions" mean the same thing, that is Alpha & Omega and first and last. Your article then quotes Isaiah 44:6 so here is my question for you? From the NWT, "This is what Jehovah has said, the King of Israel and the Repurchaser of him, Jehovah of armies. I am the first and I am the last, and besides me there is no God. Is Jehovah in this verse Jehovah the Father?

Comment: when context makes it clear that first and last is referencing death and resurrection it is referring to Jesus

Comment: @Kris That's not what I ask you. My question is very specific so I'll repeat it. At Isaiah 44:6, is Jehovah in this verse Jehovah the Father? Why the "stall," it requires a yes or no answer.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Yes, Jehovah always refers to the Father, including at Isaiah 44:6.

Comment: The latest edit makes this a non question.

Comment: @kris that's probably just a typo, but I'd have to think this question is a dupe, Mr. Bond you're free to put a bounty on the other question if you want more details

Comment: Oh on second thought,  yeah, the meat of the question is lacking.

Comment: @PeterTurner It was Kris who edited my question and I reedited it to make it more clear. This is not a duplicate question but a more clearer question? The point I am making is the fact that those who deny the deity of Jesus Christ based on Revelation 1:8 have to prove that Jesus Christ is not the speaker in the verse and I can prove it, they can't or at least they have not even given a "cogent" argument to the contrary. I answered my own question but it was deleted based on the very first two paragraphs. I ask the moderator if I could delete the first two paragraphs and no answer.

Comment: @mr. please just read your post as written from top to bottom (revert if you want).  You've got no question there.  It's a statement ending in a question mark followed by 4 bible verse.   Clearly needs some work.   The criteria for "questionhood" is in the body of the question, even if you restate the title, it really needs to be there.  Sorry for being so rigid, but I am a moderator here after all; there are objective standards that have nothing to do doctrine at play here.

Comment: @PeterTurner I see what you mean so I will reword it in the form of a question? Sort of like the game show "Jeopardy?" Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Ok it’s a question again!!! And exactly the same as how I had edited it.

Comment: @Kris Good, I'm glad I can make you happy? Now, can you prove that Jesus is not the speaker?

Comment: Yes I have some video and audio from the event that I’m trying to format for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

No, Jesus is not identified as 'the Almighty', God or 'the Eternal'. This is another question seeking to verify a theology of men and not of the bible. However, he is given the name of Alpha and Omega - we will see what this means and, does not mean

*Denying Jesus' deity* is an awkward way to say that we affirm Jesus as the human son of God. Making Jesus a God/man is to trivialise his willing, obedient and trusting sacrifice.

What God *has* made known rather abundantly, is that Jesus is His human son born of Mary and called to remain without sin until finally dying on a cross as Saviour for all mankind. In his role as the son of God, through his death, he has enabled the redemption and completion of God's creation.

> yet to us there is one God the Father, of whom are all things, and we for Him; and one Lord, Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we through Him. 1Cor 8:6

Apart from the obvious declaration about 'one God the Father', the rest of this passage shows the essential role of Jesus.

All things find their fulfilment in him - not because he made everything,  but because he is the way, the only way to the Father and true life.

Jesus is not identified as THE Almighty. This is also abundantly clear in many places, and by Jesus' own words,

> And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent. John 17:3

No rational approach to the scriptures as a whole and cohesive narrative would lead to thinking Jesus is *Supreme God* when he clearly *has* a God - even once ascended this remains true.

Having ruled out that misunderstanding of scripture, why then does Jesus have this name that also is applied to God - the one true God, the God that Jesus said he had!

> I am the Alpha and the Omega,” says the Lord God Rev 1:8

Jesus is never called "Lord God" anywhere - why would John start here?

### Rev. starts with, and needs no interpretation!

> **The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him** ...

- Only those with a pre-supposed view of God and Jesus could mis-understand this simple line. Like so many other unambiguous, crystal-clear truths that tradition has masked with complexity and mystery to hide the true nature of Jesus and to minimise the true nature of God.

While the OP wants to quote titles from Revelations, he avoids the very strenuous examples of Jesus having a God - yes the exalted, now immortal Jesus, still has a God, as he always did. Rev 3:12 x 4 times!

The answer to the *sharing of Titles* is based on examples provided in both OT and NT usages. Trying to prove anything by what title God has, or is given to others, including Christ, is an exercise in curiosity but accomplishes little of any value.

King of Kings, Saviour, Lord, 'First and Last' is applied to both God and Jesus at different times and even other men who are *not* without sin.

Isaiah 44:6; 48:12 First and Last is God Rev 1:17; 2:8; 22:13 First and Last is Jesus

God the Father is called “Saviour” Is 43:11, 1 Tim 1:1; 2:3; 4:10; Tit 1:3; 2:10; 3:4; Jude 25

Jesus 1 John 4:14, Acts 5:31, Phil 3:20

Men designated as “saviour” 2 Kings 13:5; Isaiah 19:20 Obadiah 21.

We know from Isaiah and the child titled Immanuel - he wasn't God simply because his name represented "God with us", and neither should Jesus be called God because of a title he was given. Certainly, Jesus IS God with us, not because he is God, but because he is the *image*, *form*, and glory of God, representing Him perfectly.

> Anyone who has seen me has seen (or known) the Father. John 14:9

There are plentiful plainly-spoken texts that tell the truth of God and His son. Trying to force a construct of unbiblical proportions on to Jesus with verses speaking of titles and names is not a useful pursuit. The bible shows no special reservation for titles - they are conferred on men and God and His son at various places.

Alpha and Omega IS applied to both God and Jesus - but for different reasons.

God is obviously the beginning and the end of all things. Christ is the beginning and the end because he is the firstborn from the dead, the author and finisher of faith for a couple of examples.

Alpha and Omega are two Greek letters! There is nothing about this we know from other texts - it's just an expression signifying uniqueness and special role. Deducing anything else is pure speculation. A cursory glance at Revelation reveals the Lamb is NOT GOD, and God is NOT the Lamb. So why would this title make ANY difference to our understanding of who Jesus is relative to his God and Father?

While we might try to identify Jesus according to tradition, he certainly does not self-identify as God.

> Jesus said to her, “Stop clinging to me, for I have not yet ascended to the Father; but go to my brothers and say to them, ‘I am ascending to my Father and your Father, and my God and your God.’” John 20:17

++++++++++

We love to ponder Thomas and his statement, “My Lord and my God".

We have two options.

1. put this, *unusual comment* in sync with the rest of the bible.
2. reorient everything else to sync with Thomas. Thomas wasn't wrong in what he said, but any interpretation cannot be allowed to have a life of its own. We are not to use an ambiguous text to explain all the others. I have addressed Thomas [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/does-the-greek-of-john-2028-address-two-persons-or-one/51196?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C18.0483#51196)

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, except that you don't seem to address Rev 1:8 directly. AFAICT it seems the Father is speaking at Rev 1:8.

Comment: good point, ta.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather It is a very good point and how do you know God the Father is speaking? Show me from the text itself or from the surrounding context it is God the Father speaking? The only way it will work for you (but you would still be in error) is if your a Oneness Pentecostal/Modalist, are you? It is clearly obvious that the speaker is Jesus Christ, prove it otherwise?

Comment: @Mr.Bond The text seems to work pretty straightforwardly at Rev 1 if you assume 1:8 refers to the Father, IMO. Nope, definitely not a Pentecostal! I'm a Biblical Unitarian as far as this issue goes. Perhaps post another question with this specifically and notify me?

Comment: Minor point: You state that **”Jesus is never called "Lord God" anywhere - why would John start here?”** Yet St. John does not object to St. Thomas calling Jesus: [**”My Lord and my God!”**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_20:28)

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, you have two options. You can put this, let's say 'unusual comment' in sync with the rest of the bible. Or you can reorient everything else to sync with Thomas. Thomas wasn't wrong in what he said, but our subsequent interpretation cannot be allowed to have a life of its own.  We are not permitted to use an ambiguous text to explain all the others. I have addressed Thomas here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/does-the-greek-of-john-2028-address-two-persons-or-one/51196?r=SearchResults&s=1|18.0483#51196

Comment: @steveowen Ya, I agree that the 'Thomas was mistaken' response sometimes given by non-trinitarians is weak. What you say here seems absolutely right to me - in exegesis, you should start with a solid, relatively unambiguous foundation, not an ambiguous one. That Jesus = God requires a foundation based on ambiguous verses or textual variants is telling IMO. Thomas' exclamation is the strongest of all verses for Jesus = God, but in context it is very ambiguous, and something like what you say at the link seems more plausible. John 14 is the key. +1

Comment: @OneGodtheFather How about 2 Peter 1:1, the very first verse? "Simon Peter, a bond-servant and apostle of Jesus Christ, to those who have received a faith of the same kind as ours, by the righteousness  of our God and Savior, Jesus Christ." Did you receive the same kind of righteousness as Peter from "our God and Savior, Jesus Christ?" And btw, would you consider this verse "ambiguous?" If so, how?

Comment: @Mr.Bond :) seriously, do you have to pick one verse that *seems* to fit your agenda against all the others that do not? What kind of wisdom does that? God doesn't make it confusing or contradictory - we do in our reading and sometimes, just in punctuating. Go to Paul and Rev and see all the places where J *clearly* has a God, therefore is NOT God, and fit that into your theology - it won't. Yet you thrust out with 2 Peter 1:1 as if it was the ultimate proof text! Desperate measures Mr Bond. The house of cards is tottering.

Comment: @steveowen You want "seriously?" Here are 5 verses declaring Jesus is God off the top of my head. Titus 2:13, 2 Peter 1:1, Revelation 1;8, Hebrews 1:8 and here's an oldie but goodie, John 20:28. Here's 5 verse you would use to say Jesus is not God but a man only. John 17:3, John 5:44, 1 Corinthians 8:4,6, Ephesians 4:4-6, Acts 2:22. So how would you determine which one of us is right? I ask you to reconcile verses that appear contradictory? Obviously you can't do it. Your position is akin to you trying to reorganize deck chairs on the Titanic. In other words, you don't have a valid argument.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Sounds like the basis for another question, but yes, that verse is quite ambiguous. In a nut-shell, 1. Epistles usually open with greetings from both God and Jesus (Rom. 1:7; 1 Cor. 1:3; Gal. 1:3, and so on), so it would be unusual for this one to open with a statement that Jesus is God. 2. Peter speaks of God and Jesus in the same verse on a number of occasions, and never equates Jesus with God in them, but speaks of them as being different (1 Pet. 1:2, 3; 2:5; 3:21; 4:11; 5:10; 2 Pet. 1:2). ...

Comment: @Mr.Bond ... God and Jesus are referred to as separate in the other epistles, which again would make this an unusual reading. 3. There are many non-trinitarian ways to translate 2 Peter 1:1 (cf. ASV, NOY, CJB, Weymouth, Rotherham, Noah Webster, Estes). 4. There are Aramaic, Latin, Coptic, Sahidic, and Greek manuscripts (including Sinaiticus and (044)) that have 'Lord' instead of God, and read, 'our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ.' Translations from the Aramaic read 'our Lord and our Savior, Jesus Christ'. So yes, 2 Peter 1:1 is ambiguous.